# Trouble Debugging After Combining Multiple .NET Solutions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

How I got to where I am now.  I have 3 "child" solutions (web applications) I want to combine into 1 "parent" solution (web application).

To my parent solution I added 3 new solution folders.  To each solution folder I choose "Add existing project..."  There I selected the *.sln of each respective child project.

I've consolidated/excluded the child:  Web.Config files, Global.asax, CSS and C# classes into their respective files in the parent project.

The parent solution builds successfully.  The *.aspx files in the parent solution function as expected in debug mode.

The question/problem I have is around linking to *.aspx files in the child solutions.  I've been unable to find a URL in debug mode that will direct me to the intended *.aspx in a child solution.  I keep getting 404's for the *.aspx files I've tried to browse to, in the child solutions.

If I had to guess I need to make a change to the "Web" tab on the Properties page of the child solutions...  But, I'm not sure what changes to make.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you have multiple startup projects configured?

Comment: The folders effect the web page output.  Publish the web pages and look at the folder structure.  Add the folder name to the link.  e.g. `/ChildProject1/Home.aspx`.

Comment: I set the "Always Start When Debugging" property of each child solution to false...b/c if I didn't when I started Debug mode it opened 4 separate "development servers"

Comment: Marc I selected the "parent" project as the startup project, and I checked each "child" project's checkbox in the dependencies section under "common properties".

Comment: P.Brian.Mackey I published the parent, and subsequently each individual project into folders under the published parent site.  How does that help me know the appropriate link for child project *.aspx files in debug mode?

Comment: I didn't want multiple startup projects, and a single Visual Studio development server cannot host multiple solutions.  I think the answer would be to look at using the "local IIS server option".  This isn't an option for me, and I didn't want to go the route of remote debugging against a web server, so I've gone a whole different direction and now I'm combining the code from the different solutions into one solution.